# Duplicating a chart header across multiple pages of print

Tags: javascript, css, charts, anychart

I am creating a charting solution using AnyChart. This chart needs to span across multiple pages, as the chart's length is dynamic according to the data that it's charting. The issue I'm having, however, is that I need the ability to have the chart headers show on each page when printed. There is no way to do this using AnyChart's platform, so I'm curious: is there any way, using CSS/JavaScript, to take an element on a page and duplicate it on each printed page as a page header?

[image: Here is an image of the chart]

Comment: What part of the chart's length being dynamic necessitates it spanning multiple pages?

Comment: @AndrueAnderson  
Many of these charts extend down beyond 1,000 feet (the y-axis is in feet). Often, there will be segments that are so close together and so small that, even expanded over 20-plus pages, they still blend together. You can see in the image, on the right-most column, there are segments that already blend together, and the chart in that picture is set to print over 15 pages.

Comment: have you tried to create text labels with chart titles on the pages using AnyChart API? like custom labels: https://api.anychart.com/7.8.0/anychart.ui.Label# or graphics to define text elements: http://docs.anychart.com/7.8.0/Graphics/Basics#text_and_image

Comment: I believe you are combining two different things ... an Anychart chart is a chart ... a picture ... an image for all purposes. What you are asking is like if I printed a picture of my dog ... it would have [My dog ... continued] and the bottom half of my dog on the second page should my dog not fit on a page. You have to reconstruct all of what you are doing to achieve such a thing.